# using cache in dot net Mvc business logic dll n-tiers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, logic

i'm writing an MVC project with N-tiers in the business Logic Dll
i need to get a list from the database and save it in cache (it must be there )
and not in the project itself
the problem is that i cant use  cache there , such as  HttpRuntime.Cache["dict"]
and cant using using System.Web.mvc;

is there any other way to save fast data for all users ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You implement a read data access object through which all of your code reads this list from the database. You cache the list there and do hard reads when your cache expires. Do not forget to use a semaphore to lock your cache while updating to prevent multi-threading issues.

Comment: hi, i canwt do it, i will explain, my projecthave business logic dll and the other poject with the vies etc, in the business logic i wrote extention for the DISPLAY NAME, for example insted of " [Display(Name = "Family name")]"   now i have "[LocalizedDisplayName("LastName", "tblMain")]"   and in the class "LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute" i'm taking from the DataBase the cultures terms So the HTML HELPERS  can use  a  Dictunary.